# galeria con grid

Tags: css, imagen, frontend, gallery, width

[image: galeria]

como hago para que la galeria ocupe todo el ancho de la pagina?
le puse a las imagenes un width de 100% y al grid-template-columns 1fr como maximo para que se expandan pero no sirve

Comment: En el .grid-container pones `width:100%`